# Android push notification unable to recreate activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

In my application I unable to recreate the activity with new information (bundle data) when tap push notification. The following is the steps of my push notification process flow.

Step 1:
I open Activity B from when click the push notification with information showing in the Activity B.

Step 2:
Tap home button or go to some other activity so Activity B goes to background (OnPause) state.

Step 3:
Now again I open Activity B via clicking push notification  with new information but `Activity B goes to onResume instead of onCreate state`.

My requirement is it should go to onCreate state so that I can process the  with the new information. How can IActivity B goes to onResume instead of onCreate state do this? I did the following in the notification receiver class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListScreenActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("res_id", requestCode);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("uid", id_value);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent,0);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
Notification notification = mBuilder
         .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
         .setTicker(tickerMessage)
         .setWhen(0)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setContentTitle(app_name)
         .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(tickerMessage)
         .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
         .setContentText(tickerContent).build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
```

Note:
here `ListScreenActivity (Activity B) is not Launcher activity`

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the Android activity lifecycle.  You should expect this same thing can happen every time.  onCreate is only called once per instance of an activity object.  That can't be changed.  You can read about the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close existing activity stack regardless of what's in there and create new root, correct set of flags is the following:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```